# Cmd cannot find a mapped drive

Tags: windows-7, networking, mapped-drive

Here's my problem:

we have a network drive that's mapped to `T:\`, and it's pointing to `\\somecomputer\somefolder\`.

We can run: `\\somecomputer\somefolder\someapp.exe` from cmd.

We can also run `pushd \\somecomputer\somefolder\`.

We cannot run `pushd T:\`, and several applications cannot resolve the path `T:\someapp.exe`.

What would some potential causes of this problem be?

Comment: My first guess is that you are running cmd in a different user context. Do you see the drive if you do this at in the cmd prompt:  ***net use***

Comment: @EBGreen, it is there.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that `cmd` is running in elevated mode (ie. with `Run as administrator` selected). The problem is discussed in greater detail [here](http://www.winability.com/how-to-make-elevated-programs-recognize-network-drives/).

The solution is to use `net use` to mount the drive or simply merge this into your registry:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System]
"EnableLinkedConnections"=dword:00000001
```

A reboot is required after making the above change.